# c# sockets CONNECTIONS

Tags: .net, sockets, c#-4.0, tcp

I'm trying to open a socket for wireless connection and from what I understand I need to open port 8888. What is this port? See link:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you meant to ask what the meaning of this port is, it's not registered or known to be used by anything significant. IANA says it has at some point been used by a ["NewsEDGE server"](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers), which I can't even find via a Google search. It's just a random port the person who wrote the tutorial chose to use as an example.

Answer (score 0):

8888 is the number of the port. That could be anything listening to that port.

IANA has a [list of registered ports](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers), but for private applications you usually borrow a port number that you don't expect to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody that writes an application that listens on a socket must pick a port number that's unique to the specific protocol he uses.  It is not a completely free choice, the application on the other end of the wire needs to use the same port number.  And having two distinct apps with different protocols listen on the same port is disastrous.  Furthermore, the firewall has to be opened for the port.

Picking a number like 8888 is the proper thing to do.  Although it is a bit unimaginative, the risk for picking the same number as used by a random other app is not zero.  These apps usually have a backdoor, a config file that lets you choose another one in case that happens.